# Why by clicking on add products button I received category empty at first index?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Why by clicking on add products button I received category name empty at first index.
1.It starts text from index 2 of category  column.
2.when I change value from dropdown first it display previous value in category column and then by clicking on add products button it gives selected value.3.
3.I am attaching picture and code so that it will be more clear.

no category name at index 1:

[image: no category name at index 1]

by changing dropdwon first it give previous value:

[image]

```
@extends('layouts.home')
@section('content')

<style>
.btn-circle.btn-xl { 
            width: 100px; 
            height: 40px; 
            padding: 6px 0px; 
            border-radius: 20px; 
            font-size: 12px; 
            text-align: center; 
           margin-top:2%;
           margin-left:2%;
        } 
        .btn-circle.btn-sm { 
            width: 40px; 
            height: 40px; 
            padding: 6px 0px; 
            border-radius: 20px; 
            font-size: 10px; 
            text-align: center; 
        } 
  @media screen{

    
  }
  @media print {
    .btn{
      display:none;
      border:0px;
    }
    .form-control{
      border:0px;
    }
    .input-group-text{
      border:0px;
      background-color: white;
    }
   

  }
 
  .ml-0 {
  margin-left:60%  !important;
}
.mb-0 {
  margin-bottom:20%  !important;
  
}

    </style>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
  
    <!-- Main content -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- left column -->
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- jquery validation -->
            <div class="card card-primary">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="text-center">Purchase Products</h4>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <!-- form start -->
              <div class="card-body">
              <form action="{{route('product.store')}}" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
              
              
                @csrf
                 <div class="row">
                
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                     <label for="first_name"> Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" required="" name="date">
                  </div>
                
                  
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                   <label for="email">Product Code No.</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="code" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="last_name">Supplier</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="supid"  name="supid" required>
    <option value="">Add Supplier</option>    
    @foreach($sup as $supid): 
    <option value="{{$supid->supplierid}}">{{$supid->name}}</option>
    @endforeach                 
    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="last_name">Catogory</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="catid"   required>
                  <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select catagory</option>
          
    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="last_name">Product Name</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="pid"  name="pid" required>
                  <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select product</option>
    </select>
    </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mt-4">
                   
                  <button type="button" onclick="addrow(this)" id="find" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle nav-icon"></i>Add Products</button> 
                  </div>
                  
                  </div>
                </div>

<body>
  <div class="container border ">
    <h1 class="text-center">INVOICE</h1>
    
    <div class="" >
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable" id="table-2>tbody" >
        <thead class="table-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" >#SR</th>
            <th scope="col">CATAGORY</th>
            <th scope="col">PRODUCT NAME</th>
            <th scope="col">PCS/PKTS</th>
            <th scope="col">UNIT PRICE</th>
            <th scope="col" class="">TOTAL PRICE</th>
            <th scope="col"> Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody id="imi">
          <tr id="add" class="d-none" class="tabRow" id="imgbox" name="imisix">
            <td class="serialNo"  id="serialNo"></td>
            
            <td id="show_cat" name="show_cat"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="total" name="total" ></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="discount" name="discount" onkeyup="discount(this)"
                onblur="calcSum()"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="discount" name="disc"  id="abcd"
                class="txtCal"></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm" class="NoPint" onclick="delrow(this)">delete row</button></td>
          </tr>
          
        </tbody>
       
      </table>
      
    </div>
    <form>
  <div class="">
      <div class="row" class="">
        <div class="ml-0" style="">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2"></label>
        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">Total</div>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total_amount" disabled id="total_amount" placeholder="Username">

        </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="row" class="">
  <div class="ml-0" style="">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2"></label>
        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">GST</div>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="GSTimi" onblur="calcGST()" id="GST_amount"
            placeholder="Username">

        </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="row" >
      <div class="ml-0" style="">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2"></label>

        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">Total With GST</div>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="GST_amount" disabled onblur="totalGST()" id="total_GST"
            placeholder="Username">

        </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
   
  </form>
</div>
</body>

                <!-- /.card-body -->
               
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Submit</button>
                </div>
                 
              </form>
             </div>
              
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
            </div>
          <!--/.col (left) -->
          <!-- right column -->
          
          <!--/.col (right) -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>


  
  <script>
    $(document).on('change','#supid',function(){
        var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    
    var suplierId = $('#supid').val();
    //alert(productId)
   // console.log(productId); 
  var op=" ";
    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        data:{'suplierId':suplierId,_token:_token},
        url:"{{ route('get.catagory') }}",
    success:function(data){
        op+='<option value="" selected   disabled>select catagory</option>';
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    op+='<option value="'+data[i].catagoriesid+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';

          
          }
          $('#catid').html(" ");
                   $('#catid').append(op);
       console.log(data);
    }
        })
    
});
$(document).on('change','#catid',function(){
        var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    
    var catidId = $('#catid').val();
  //  alert(catidId)
   // console.log(productId); 
  var op=" ";
    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        data:{'catidId':catidId,_token:_token},
        url:"{{ route('get.productname') }}",
    success:function(data){
        op+='<option value="0" selected name="catid" disabled>select product</option>';
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    op+='<option value="'+data[i].productsid+'">'+data[i].product_name+'</option>';      
          }
          $('#pid').html(" ");
                   $('#pid').append(op);
     //  alert(data);
    }
        })
    
});
 // document.getElementById("imi").children[0].style.background="red";;
  // var childdd= document.getElementById("imi").children;
  // console.log(childdd);
  function getPrice(imi) {
     // alert('s');
     let u = $(imi).parent().parent().index();
     alert(u);
     // document.getElementById("imgbox2").style.visibility = "visible";
     let x = document.getElementsByName("price")[u].value;
     //let x= $("#price").val();
     // alert(x);
     let y = document.getElementsByName("quantity")[u].value;

     let z = x * y;
     document.getElementsByName("total")[u].value = z;
     //let u=imi.value;
     //let b=z-10;
     //alert(z)
     //document.getElementById("disc").value=b; 
     //z= discount=(x*y)/100-x;

   }
   function discount(imi) {
     let e = $(imi).parent().parent().index();
   alert(e)
     z = document.getElementsByName("total")[e].value;
     //let z=x*y;
     //alert(z);
     let u = document.getElementsByName("discount")[e].value;
     let b = z - z * (u / 100);
     //alert(b)
     document.getElementsByName("disc")[e].value = b;
     //alert(z)
   }
   
     function addrow(imi) {
       var v = $("#add").clone().appendTo("#imi");

       $(v).find("input").val('');
       $(v).removeClass("d-none");

       let shx =  $("#catid option:selected").text();
document.getElementById("show_cat").innerHTML=shx;
        function addSerialNumber() {

$(' table tbody tr').each(function(index) {
// alert(index)
   $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').html(index);
});
};

addSerialNumber();

       
     
// alert(index)

 // $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html(res);
 


 
// function showcat(imi) {
//       //  let e = $(this).index();
//        // alert(e)
//      //  let shx= document.getElementById("catid").innerHTML;
//        let shx=  $("#catid option:selected").text();
//       console.log(shx)
//       document.getElementById("show_cat").innerHTML=shx;
//     //  show_cat
// }
// showcat();

      
     }
     
   
    

   // var display=d.options[d.selectedIndex(1)].text;
     
      
    // // Let's test it out
    // alert(shx);





     function delrow(v) {
       //alert(v)
       var f = $(v).parent().parent().remove();
//alert(f)
       var calculated_total_sum = 0;
       // alert( calculated_total_sum)
       $('input[name="disc"]').each(function () {
         var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
         // alert( get_textbox_value)
         if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
           calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
          // alert(calculated_total_sum)
         }
       });
       document.getElementById("total_amount").value = (calculated_total_sum);

     }
     function calcSum() {
       var calculated_total_sum = 0;

       $('input[name="disc"]').each(function () {
         var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
         //alert( get_textbox_value)
         if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
           calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
           //alert(calculated_total_sum)
         }
       });
       document.getElementById("total_amount").value = calculated_total_sum;
     }

     function calcGST() {
       GST = parseFloat(document.getElementById("GST_amount").value);
       // alert(GST)
       previoussum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total_amount").value);
       //alert(previoussum)
       TOTAL = previoussum * (GST / 100);
       totalwithgst = TOTAL + previoussum
       document.getElementById("total_GST").value = totalwithgst;

     }

     function myFunction()
{
window.print();
}
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
        $('#btnnn').prop("disabled", true);
        $('#GST_amount').keyup(function(){
        //  alert('hh')
           if($(this).val()!=''){
            $('#btnnn').prop("disabled", false);
           }
        });
    });

//var f= $(v).parent().parent().remove()
//discountamount(;
 @if(Session::has('message'))
     swal({
  title: "Good job!",
  text: "Data Entered  Successfully!",
  icon: "success",
});
  @endif
</script>
@endsection
```

I have tried to fix problem by using .each loop but the problem was still there. I do not want my first category Colum empty and also by charging category it gives proper text.

Comment: Is this mountain of code really a [mre] of the issue? Please try to make it more focused, and also format the code and indentations so it's readable. You can [edit] your post.

Comment: In same code. when i submitt values in tr with d-none class are not submitted even i use removeclass method

Comment: Stick to one problem at a time and address the issue i mentioned in my first comment. Then we might be able to help you. See also [ask]. Thanks

Comment: previous problem about catagory index has been solve by adding few line of code by myself  let cat_selected =  $("#catid option:selected").text();
      // alert(cat_selected)
       let pid_selected =  $("#pid option:selected").text();
       $(v).find('td:nth-child(2)').html(cat_selected);
       $(v).find('td:nth-child(3)').html(pid_selected);

Comment: OK. So if you have a new problem, delete this post and ask a new question with updated code, focusing on that problem only. Again...[ask]. Don't daisy-chain different issues onto the same post, that's not how stackoverflow works

Answer (score 1):

problem has been solved by adding code below

```
let cat_selected =  $("#catid option:selected").text();
      // alert(cat_selected)
       let pid_selected =  $("#pid option:selected").text();
       $(v).find('td:nth-child(2)').html(cat_selected);
       $(v).find('td:nth-child(3)').html(pid_selected);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: dear i have solved that issue, but i am facing new issue. When i add row i am receiving null values of all td which i add with add button